# Special chars in select

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

I have select what looks like this:

```
mSelectionClause = "(lower(" + NAME_COLUMN + ") LIKE \'%" + name.toLowerCase() + "%\'";
```

However, when I set the name to something like '" app crash with:

```
Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near ""%' OR upper(display_name) LIKE '%'''''"": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: (...)
```

How can I prevent from special chars in value to select?

Comment: Please use query parameters instead of string interpolation!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this.
As this will escape your special characters.

```
name = DatabaseUtils.sqlEscapeString(name);
```

Comment: not as good as i want to, when i have to use % or _ this also disable it

Comment: @Mariusz `sqlEscapeString` escapes only single quotes.

Answer (score 0):

To prevent string formatting problems in SQL commands, use parameters:

```java
mSelectionClause = NAME_COLUMN + " LIKE ?";
String[] selectionArgs = new String[] { name };
db.query(table, cols, mSelectionClause, selectionArgs, null, null, null);
```

(LIKE is case insensitive.)